# AppleID Signin Loop?

Tags: ios, itunes-store

I was testing different Receipt verification codes on my app and I might have ran a code that had a loop. Now I keep getting the 'Sign in to iTunes Store' prompting for my password whenever I launch the app. It is a sandbox tester AppleID. Nothing I did seem to stop it from popping up. I have tried deleting the app, cleaning via Xcode, rebooting, signed out of iCloud, itunes, Music, Videos - everything.

Signing in with the correct password removes the prompt only for the time being and then it will pop back up again whenever the app is launched. There is NO extra code running when it is signed in/cancelled.

Comment: Please provide code or more specific information on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is. I think an IAP got stuck while downloading and caused the error. Anyway I just did a "Reset All Settings" under Settings > General > Reset and everything was fine after. It did prompt one last time with a pop up asking for my password (again) to "finish downloading" (something) and that was it.